# Use AutoHotKey to assign shortcut to VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, autohotkey

is there any way to assign AutoHotKey shortcut key to VBA Macro.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
~Alt::vkFF
!h:: ->VBA procedure
#If
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Why use a 3rd-party script when [the feature already exists](https://superuser.com/a/1650011/165271)?

Comment: This is because Alt+H cannot be used in the Macro Window (link u shared) and Alt+H will  activate the home tab, thus not able to link my procedure.

Answer (score 1):

**AHK code:**  (with error handling and debugging statements)

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
~Alt::vkFF
!h:: 
    try {
        XL := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
    } catch {
        MsgBox, 16,, Cann't obtain Excel! 
        return
    }
    MsgBox, 64,, Excel obtained successfully!   ;for debugging purposes
    try {
        XL.Run("theSub")
    } catch {
        MsgBox, 16,, Cann't find "theSub" in the opened workbook!
    }
#If
```

**VBA code:**

```
' placed in VBAProject/Modules/Module1
Option Explicit

Sub theSub()
    MsgBox "It's running"
End Sub
```

**After press Alt+h:**  (AHK script running, Excel running, the workbook with theSub procedure is open and active)
[image]

Comment: Did you replace "theSub" with your own procedure's name ? Is you procedure placed a) in the opened workbook, b) in the common (non-class) module?